# Why is the vibration duration in iOS not configurable (React Native)?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am creating a game in React Native and I've searched all over the internet, Why is the vibration duration in iOS not configurable in React Native? All it says in the React Native docs is that the vibration duration in iOS not configurable but no other explanation.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/vibration
The reason why I would like to know why is because I would like to know if it would be possible for me to make a node module to work around this.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to iOS 13 , the only *public* vibrate API available to developers is a simple fixed length buzz via `AudioToolbox`. You can see in [the React Native repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Vibration/RCTVibration.mm) that this is implemented in native code as a one liner.

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

There is the [UIFeedbackGenerator API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator) available since iOS 10 to access the Taptic Engine but that's not appropriate for use in a game.

In iOS13 developers gained diverse access to the Taptic Engine via [CoreHaptics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corehaptics)

If you were committed to getting a custom vibrate pattern for iOS you would need to

- Build it (probably in Objective-C)
- Restrict the functionality to only iOS13 and iPhone. No iPads have haptic hardware.
- Submit a PR (or fork and build ReactNative for yourself)

A possible research path might be to see if CoreHaptics can be accessed via Javascript.

Comment: Vibration is not only about haptics.

Comment: True, I have used the word haptic where vibrate might more appropriate in a couple of places.